# Entity Framework and 3 layer architecture

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture

I have a three layer architecture program. The questions are:
1. Data access is the layer of EF?
2. If i want to use an entity generated by EF from Presentation Layer, then i reference the Data Access, but this violates the principles of 3 layered architecture.

Comment: croisharp when you reference your EF Model from Presentation layer or in your Handlers project (logic) you're just asking for the model definition (Classes), your data base access still remains in your Data Layer, so don't worry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes EF would be your Data Access Layer.
With EF you can use T4 templates with POCO support, you can then extract these POCO into a seperate dll and this will be reference from all of your layers.

Comment: +1 Using POCO's provides the required level of abstraction that ensures that the integrity of the architecture is maintained. The proof? You can replace the data access implementation but retain the POCO's as the data contracts.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Spain released a pretty good documentation, guide and sample application for N-layered applications on codeplex, you can look it up here:

http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/

You will find many directions and helpful implementation patterns there.

hth.

Answer (score 1):

What type of application are you building?  If you are building an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, you can have your View be the presentation layer, your Model is your data access (which can use EF) and the controller and / or Action Filters can contain your business logic and in this scenario you will be using your EF Model in the presentation layer but still satisfy the separation of concerns principle.

Comment: I build wcf services, using netTcpBinding, but with architecture that provie web service software factory. It will not be an error in architecture if i reference data access from my Service Implementation, or in any other application from Presentation Layer?

Comment: I think the key goal in any abstraction model is to limit dependencies, so if you had a SQL statement in your ServiceContract then I would say that your Service implementation is 'too dependent' on your Data Access.  but EF, in and of itself, provides abstraction.  What I would suggest for you is to create a repository class which abstracts your service from your EF Context.  Am I answering your question?

Comment: Sure, i did the abstraction with Manager, which performs the Delete, Edit, GetById, GetAll, Add methods, but that is Business Logic, i mean the entities that was generated like Customer, Producer...

Answer (score 1):

EF does two things: -

1) Generates an domain model for you (optional, but commonly used)
2) Gives you the ability to query / modify your database via that domain model.

This can give the appearance of blurring the lines between domain model and data access but the two are indeed separate.

As long as you're not doing stuff like creating object contexts and writing queries directly in your presentation tierthen IMHO you are not breaking abstraction - the only thing you are "breakin"g is the fact that you will need to reference System.Data.Objects (or whatever the EF dll is) in your presentation project(s) (which is just a physical artifact) unless you go down the route suggested by Jethro to generate your domain model into a separate project.

Answer (score 0):

For the three tier architecture. I would consider doing Abstraction using Domain Model and Data model pattern rather then doing direct EF from Presentation Layer.

So the idea is that you have your Data Model which has EF POCO classes with Repositories which knows how to access these Classes for various CRUDs.

Your Domain Model would have models related to your Client (so you can put various ViewModels or Validation related code), It can be a WPF or MVC web app. 
Now between these two there is a business which talks to both Domain and Data models.

Your Presentation Layer does know nothing about the EF/Data Layer/Repository. When you want to introduce new Data Framework or database, you just need to write new repository classes and data models classes (which prob. be with some sort of code gen).

This also allows your code to be Unit testable as well.